# strange output: Opengl

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I have to create a room using openGL and glut. From what I see in the output it looks like the left wall gets drawn but I can't see the front wall at all.  I only have to draw 2 walls and have the camera pointing towards the corner where the 2 walls meet.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

My code:

```
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>

/*defining colors used in the room*/
GLfloat black[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
GLfloat white[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
GLfloat brown[] = {165.0/255.0, 42.0/255.0, 42.0/255.0, 1.0};

void drawFloor()
{
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor4fv(black);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, -3.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, -3.0);
    glVertex3f(2.0, 0.0, -3.0);
    glEnd();
}

void drawWalls()
{
    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    glColor4fv(white);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);
    int i;
    //draw left wall
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, i);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, i);
    }
    //draw front wall
    for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        glVertex3f(i, 0, 5);
    }
    glEnd();
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  1.0, 0.0);
    drawFloor();
    drawWalls();
    glFlush();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60, (GLfloat) w / (GLfloat) h, 1, 500);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void idleFunc()
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("My room");
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutIdleFunc(idleFunc);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: can you provide an image of what you see?

Comment: Why are you using `GLUT_DOUBLE` without `glutSwapBuffers()`?  Why are you trying to call `glPolygonMode()` inside a `glBegin()`/`glEnd()` pair?  Why haven't you enabled depth testing?

Comment: Bear in mind that the "front" of a polygon is when the vertices are ordered counter-clockwise, not clockwise.

Comment: I removed the GL_Polygon and added glutSwapBuffers in the display function.  The image I get as output is a white triangle on a black background...  As I said i'm a complete beginner so it's very likely that i'll continue for a while making mistakes such as those.  Are my wall drawing functions correct?  feels like i'm missing something major somewhere...  Thanks a lot everyone that responded...